# Displaying multiple video streams in one winform in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, win32gui

i want to develop a windows application in c++ that could be draw multiple video streams that come from network in one window (like video conference applications).
in another words, i want to have one window and split this window into sections that each section show a video stream.(like what we see in video conference applications like oovoo or webex).

how i can start learning and witch subject important here i Google the net but can not find any article or example about this subject.

please guide me
 thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a similiar project, which shows 4 different videos in window. These videos were coming from network(TCP/IP) connection. I used VLC for encoding the videos. (Videos are in mp4 format.) Also I used QT for GUI design. Since QT has phonon framework after qt release 4.5, I guess you can use QT for both encoding videos and gui design.

You can check it here: 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html

Comment: emreakyilmaz thank for repy.
i am not familiar with QT and it's UI engine.is QT usable on windows desktop applications?
is there another solution? i want to do this without any third party project or framework.
my problem exactly is UI design.

Comment: You can use qt for windows desktop application. Qt has everything you need. Actually I dont know any other solution but for video encoding I guess you need an application or library. At least you have to use ffmpeg plugin to show your videos. Are you using visaul studio? If you are using visual studio then opensource vlc is an option for you. You can check VLC from website:http://www.videolan.org/vlc/#download

Comment: thanks
my framework is ready to use and what's problem here is , experience of GUI programming in VC++. i think it is better to use QT GUI and start learning it